# How to run an exe file from Custom Action in InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition( VS2013)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am Working on Windows Application (VS 2013) . I am using Installshield 2015 Limited Edition for Setup. I want to install a certificate when the setup file is installed or executed   i.e , In installshield setup, Adding a Vbscript and Exe file(to install certificate) in "Custom Action During Installation", adding those file again in "Custom Action During Maintaenance"  .
But Custom Actions are not working.
Note: Since this was not working, installing certificate I am doing this in the code, which I am not supposed to do.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: What is not working? Did you get an error?

Comment: No Jeroen... I am not getting any error. When I install the setup file, it should install the certificates i.e In Custom Action, I have added the exe and vbs file(both intsall certificate). 
Does InstallShield  Custom Action in 2015 Limited Edition work?

Comment: I think  Custom Actions are not working in Limited Edition. Should go for Express Edition or  Professional Edition. Please correct me if I am  wrong